# How to access viewstate using javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, viewstate

I am trying to access view-state in client side but following exception coming :
[image]

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var vCode = '<%=ViewState("code")%>';
    alert(dateView);
</script>
```

**CODE BEHIND:**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ViewState("code") = "EE"
End Sub
```

Anybody suggest me how to do it?

Comment: Thanks guys for reply.i have seen in one of the project accessing view-state like above and working properly but in my project its giving me exception why?Do i have have to do any config settings.I tried a lot but i didn't identify the reason why its working properly in that project.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I would suggests to use RegisterHiddenField than mixing server/js codes:

You may try this sample:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    ViewState("code") = "EE"
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("vCode", ViewState("code"))
End Sub
```

On your javascript:

```
var vCode = document.getElementById("vCode");
alert(vCode);
```

Comment: var vCode = document.getElementById("vCode");
alert(vCode.value);

Answer (score 6):

You can simply access the hidden form element that holds the viewstate.

The name of the control is `__viewstate`.

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="..." />

var vCode = documents.forms[0]['__VIEWSTATE'].Value;
alert(dateView);
```

Of course, this will give you the encrypted/encoded/compressed viewstate.

If you want specific values from it, you may find it better to record them in hidden fields and access those.

Answer (score 6):

The Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField did not work for me and returned null. 
You can do like this:

**1-First solution:**
define a hidden field and make sure you set runat=server

```
  <input type="hidden"  id="myhiddenField" runat="server" value="" />
```

then in your code behind assign any value you want to it

```
 myhiddenField.Value= ViewState["name"].ToString();// or assign any value you want
```

in your javascript access it like this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">  
         function test() 
              {
                var name = document.getElementById('myhiddenField').value;
                alert(name)
             }
 </script>
```

**2-Second solution**

In case for some reasons you don't want to have a server input control you can put the hidden field in a literal tag

```
<asp:literal id="literal1" runat="server"><input type="hidden" id="myhiddenField" value="{0}"/></asp:literal>
```

and then assign a value to the literal in codebehind like this

```
literal1.Text = string.Format(literal1.Text, "somevalue");  // somevlue can be your ViewState value
```

then access it in javascript as usual

```
   var name = document.getElementById('myhiddenField').value;
            alert(name)
```

Note: if you are using update panels put the hiddenfields inside the contenttemplate tag of the updatepanel

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your javascript code like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var vCode = '<% = code %>';
    alert(dateView);
</script>
```