# Highlight textbox when textChanged in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am highlighting textboxes after somebody changes its text on my asp.net form. Currently I am using `jquery`, But unfortunately, the highlight will be removed after a `postback` in `asp.net`. Is there any way for the modified-text `class` to be persisted after `postback`? Will this affect perfomance if I use asp.net TextChanged `event` to highlight ?

```
 $('.form-content  input, .form-content textarea, .form-content select').change(function (e) {
      $(this).addClass('modified-textbox');
 });
```

Comment: you can store it in `localStorage()` or `Viewstate` http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: what you want to do on text changed ?

Comment: I want to show that the text is modified. The modified-textbox class contains a red border now.

Comment: Is viewstate accessible to javascript/jquery ?

Comment: you should used jquery text changed event for that. Example:http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_change.asp and put your logic in that event function.

Comment: can you provide us html or your .aspx code snippet? or dotnetfiddle ?

Comment: @YesudassMoses: How to access viewstate using javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980714/how-to-access-viewstate-using-javascript

Comment: The above jquery code is working fine as expected. But, the problem here is a known thing. asp.net stores everything in a viewstate. But when we set at the clientside using jquery, the viewstate is not updated, and it cannot be accessed by the asp.net. this is why the css class is removed after postback.

Answer (score 1):

Keep the initial value on the server. On postback compare the initial and the new values. If they are different, add your class to the textbox.

You can do it on text changed but the performance depends on what asynchronous postback technology are you using.