# Cannot read RegisterHiddenField value from JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to read Hidden Field as below link:

[How to access viewstate using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6980714/how-to-access-viewstate-using-javascript/6980776#6980776)

My code is exactly same the best answer but when I try to read `var vCode = document.getElementById("vCode");` vCode is always returning back as null.

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 for Web and I am coding in the VB language. What can my issue be and how can I handle it?

Is there any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: My code was the same as the link but I'm pasting my codes again.

aspx.vb code:

```
Public Class index
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page



    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If Not IsPostBack Then
            ViewState("code") = "EE"
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("vCode", ViewState("code"))

        End If
    End Sub


End Class
```

Javascript Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var vCode = document.getElementById("vCode");
    alert(vCode);

});
```

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: @Mairaj Ahmad I've edited my code.

Comment: Can u inspect your html in browser to check if hiddenfeild was actually created ?

Comment: @Mairaj Ahmad I cannot see any hidden field. after _Page.ClientScript.RegisterHiddenField("vCode", ViewState("code"))_ line, should I see the hidden element in my html?

Comment: Yes as i have said you should check the hidden element in html after page is rendered,

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `getElementsByName` not `getElementById`